# limiting the list and scroll for load more. react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

hi im using react native with sagas and redux, my problem is this one
my code does print a big list of materials with some info everything is fine.
the problem is that it loads the whole list and that makes it feel very low, so i need to improve that, i want to print like 10 items of the list and when the user scrolldown it loads another 10 and so any kind of advice would be much appreciated

this is my code where i print the list

```
    class WorkOrdersPage extends Component {
      state = {
        searched: false,
        searchSerialNumber: '',
        mockData: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        const { workOrdersRequest, token } = this.props
        workOrdersRequest(token)
      }
    _renderMockFlatList = () => {
    const { listItem, listItemLeft, listItemRightView, listItemRightViewIcon, listItemMockText } = stylesWorkOrders
    return (
      <FlatList
        style={{ opacity: 0.6 }}
        data={this.state.mockData}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <ListItem onPress={() => { }} style={[listItem, { borderColor: '#dadada' }]}>
              <Left style={listItemLeft}>
                <Thumbnail square large source={Images.noPart} />
                <Body>
                  <Text style={[listItemMockText, { width: 100 }]} />
                  <Text style={[listItemMockText, { width: 200 }]} />
                  <Text style={[listItemMockText, { marginBottom: 0, width: 70 }]} />
                </Body>
              </Left>
              <Right>
                <View style={listItemRightView}>
                  <Icon style={listItemRightViewIcon} name="ios-arrow-forward" />
                </View>
              </Right>
            </ListItem>
          )
        }}
      />
    )
  }

    _renderWorkOrder = ({ item }) => {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation
    let Description = ''
    let thumb = Images.noPart
    let borderColor = "#dadada"

    try {
      Description = item.RouteCard[0].PartInfo.Description
    } catch (err) { }

    if (item.RouteCard && item.RouteCard[0] && item.RouteCard[0].Id >= 2 && item.RouteCard[0].Id <= 10) {
      const { Id } = item.RouteCard[0]
      thumb = Images.part[Id]

      if (Id >= 0 && Id <= 4)
        borderColor = '#eb5da4'

      if (Id >= 5 && Id <= 7)
        borderColor = '#6061aa'

      if (Id >= 8 && Id <= 10)
        borderColor = '#fe9200'
    }

    const { listItem, listItemLeft, listItemLeftTextMain, listItemLeftTextSecondary, listItemRightView, listItemRightViewLabel, listItemRightViewDate, listItemRightViewIcon } = stylesWorkOrders

    return (
      <ListItem onPress={() => navigate('WorkOrderPage', { workOrderId: item.Id })}
        style={[listItem, { borderColor }]}>
        <Left style={listItemLeft}>
          <Thumbnail square large source={thumb} />
          <Body>
            <Text style={listItemLeftTextMain}>{item.WONum.toUpperCase()}</Text>
            <Text style={listItemLeftTextSecondary}>{Description}</Text>
          </Body>
        </Left>
        <Right>
          <View style={listItemRightView}>
            <Text style={listItemRightViewLabel}>Req. Date: </Text>
            <Text style={listItemRightViewDate}>{moment(item.ModifiedDate).format("ll")}</Text>
            <Icon style={listItemRightViewIcon} name="ios-arrow-forward" />
          </View>
        </Right>
      </ListItem>
    )
  }

    _renderFlatList = () => {
    const { orders, ordersBySerial } = this.props
    const data = ordersBySerial.length > 0 && this.state.searched === true ? ordersBySerial : orders
    const renderItem = ordersBySerial.length > 0 && this.state.searched === true ? this._renderWorkOrderQuickAccess : this._renderWorkOrder
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        ListEmptyComponent={this._renderEmpty}
      />)
  }

  render() {
    const { header, mainBackgroundColor, headerTitle, container } = stylesWorkOrders
    const { orders, workOrdersBySerialRequest, token, ordersBySerial } = this.props
    const { searchSerialNumber, searched } = this.state

    return (
      <Container>
        <Header style={[header, mainBackgroundColor]}>
          <Thumbnail square size={35} source={Images.logo_topBar} />
          <Title style={headerTitle}>Work Orders</Title>
        </Header>
        <Header style={mainBackgroundColor} searchBar>
          <Item style={{ borderRadius: 3, paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight: 10 }}>
            <Input
              placeholder="Type Serial Number"
              value={searchSerialNumber}
              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ searchSerialNumber: text })}
            />
            {
              searched === true ?
                <Icon name="md-close" onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({ searchSerialNumber: '', searched: false })
                }} />
                :
                <Icon name="ios-search" onPress={() => {
                  if (searchSerialNumber.length == 0) return false
                  workOrdersBySerialRequest(token, searchSerialNumber)
                  this.setState({ searched: true })
                }} />
            }
          </Item>
        </Header>
        <Content style={container}>
          {orders.length === 0 ? this._renderMockFlatList() : this._renderFlatList()}
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i don't have time now to give a full answer sorry

you have to use `onEndReached` flatlist props to load some data each time your are in the end of the list (list facebook app do for example) 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#onendreached

look on google for "pagination" concept. it's what you talking about (not returning all the data in one time).

```
    state = {
        ...
        currentPage : 0, // we keep a track inside the state on each page we are for pagination
        mockData:[]
    }


    <FlatList               
        data={this.state.mockData}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderItem(item)}
        initialNumToRender={5}   // how many item to display first
        onEndReachedThreshold={5} // so when you are at 5 pixel from the bottom react run onEndReached function
        onEndReached={() => {
            this.handleLoadMore();
        }}
    />


    handleLoadMore = async() => {

        // her you put the logic to load some data with pagination
        // for example a service who return the data of the page "this.state.currentPage"
        let newData = await myExempleService(this.state.currentPage);

        this.setState({
            mockData: [ ...mockData , ...newData]   , // concat the old and new data together
            currentPage : this.state.currentPage +1
        })

    }
```

Comment: If my API doesn't have pagination, And I got a big array of data for the first time, and I want to do this? how can i handle it?

Comment: how big is your array ?

Comment: if array is very big better to paginate it to avoid long time to get data threw mobile network. if you cant do it in API/SERVER side you can do it in mobile side. the service get all the data a put them in a variable, and return only a chunk of it ( the first 20 items for example). and when you call again the service it return the next 20 items each time

Comment: also you can display large array in one shot with recyclerlistview instead of with flatlist who is very slow with large array (+5000 items) 
https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview
don't forget to add to each items a unique id and use react.purecomponents to avoid rerender

Comment: I didn't get whats you mean by (put them in a variable, when you call again to return the next 20 items). I don't have enough time to refactoring and use recylerliatview :/, and I already open new questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61002525/how-to-add-load-more-features-if-my-api-did-not-have-pagination-react-native) can you check it?

Comment: How make reverse pagination means want to load previous data from top ?

Comment: You mean that for example Newest data are available and you want to load them ? In all case onEndReach just call à function who load data. You have to édit the api so you can paginate data and or use a timestap from where you load data at thé begginning. You also have pulltorefresh functionnality to re fresh all the data and get the Newest one. I use this

Comment: Like in fb. You load the app. When you scroll you get older post. You want New you pull down to refresh