# How to add load more features if my API did not have pagination - react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In Home screen, I get data "Songs" from API and save it in the state "Big array".
And I use `FlatList` to render it, so it rendered fine but I have a too long scroll!

so in `data` FlatList prop, I slice the array like this

```
<FlatList
   data={songs.slice(0,9)}
   ...
/>
```

and it renders 10 songs as expected :D But I want to add Load more when scroll to end

My thought is
add a flag in state like

```
state={
   page: 10
}


<FlatList
      data={songs.slice(0,this.state.page)}
      onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0}
       ...
/>


handleLoadMore = () => {
this.state.songs.length <= this.state.page ? this.setState({page: this.state.page + 10, loading: true}) : null
  };
```

So have any other thoughts How can I handle this case?

## Edit

Full FlatList code snippet

```
  // recent Songs FlatList
  _renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    const {recent_songs} = this.state;
    return (
      <TouchableNativeFeed
        key={item.id}
        onPress={() => {
          this.props.saveSongs(recent_songs, index);
          this.props.isPlaying(true);
          this.props.isPauseTrigger(!this.props.isPauseTrigger);
        }}
        background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('white')}
        delayPressIn={0}
        useForeground>
        <Card style={styles.card} noShadow={true}>
          <FastImage
            source={{uri: item.img}}
            resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover}
            style={styles.cardImg}
          />
          <Body style={styles.cardItem}>
            <View style={styles.radioCardName}>
              <View style={styles.cardViewFlex}>
                <Text
                  lineBreakMode="tail"
                  ellipsizeMode="tail"
                  numberOfLines={1}
                  style={styles.text}>
                  {item.name}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </Body>
        </Card>
      </TouchableNativeFeed>
    );
  };


{/* Recent Songs Here*/}
              <View style={{marginVertical: 10}}>
                <FlatList
                  style={{flex: 1}}
                  horizontal={true}
                  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                  data={recent_songs.slice(0, 10)}
                  contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}
                  ListEmptyComponent={<EmptyList />}
                  keyExtractor={(track, index) => track.id.toString()}
                  initialNumToRender={10}
                  renderItem={this._renderItem}
                />
              </View>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "too long scroll" ? onEndReached will not solve this issu. it just add content on the end of the list

Answer (score 0):

something like this with flatlist and local pagination

```
  constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
        this.state = {
            ...
            itemPerPage : 10
            currentPage : 1, // we keep a track inside the state on each page we are for pagination
            songs:[], // contain the songs used by flatlist to render
            allSongs : [ ] // contain all the songs returned by api
        }
    }


   async componentDidMount() {
        // get the songs from api
        let allSongs = await GetSONGS(); 
        this.setState({ allSongs   , songs: allSongs.slice(0,this.state.currentPage*this.state.itemPerPage ) });
   }


   handleLoadMore = async() => {             
        this.setState({
            songs: [ ...this.state.songs ,  allSongs.slice(this.state.currentPage*this.state.itemPerPage,(this.state.currentPage+1)*this.state.itemPerPage )   ]   , // concat the old and new data together
            currentPage : this.state.currentPage +1
        })
    }


    render(){
     return(
      <FlatList               
            data={this.state.songs}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}        
            initialNumToRender={10}   // how many item to display first
            onEndReachedThreshold={5} // so when you are at 5 pixel from the bottom react run onEndReached function
            onEndReached={() => {
                this.handleLoadMore();
            }}
        />
        )
    }
```

anyway i use `RecyclerListView` in a previous project to render list of 10 000 elements

Comment: Well, is this will slow the app? Because now we have two arrays at the end will contain the same data"songs" And I have more than one flat list on the same screen!

Comment: And if I want use RecyclerListView should I change more of my code (i added it in the question)

Comment: how much item you have ? why not just rendering all the list in the first place ? RecyclerListView  will be lighter for performance.

Comment: In Home screen I have four sections every section contains FlatList in every FlatList I have 100-250 items. If you can give some tips, or manipulate this FlatList to use RecyclerListView, that's will help

Comment: 4 flatlist in the same screen is too much in user interface specially if screen is small each one will be tiny. you use them as select ?

Comment: You're right! But that's client requirements hah, No, here's a screenshot from home screen https://imgur.com/PW53BaU

Comment: ok i see, nice app. maybe just reduce each array to max 20 items +- . 
see how to optimise flatlist on google (unique id, purecomponents , arrow function ...) . in debug mod app is MUUCCH slower that in production mode, try it and see if you have lag

Comment: Oh, thanks, I will search about it, in the previous version (with using unique id, pure component, arrow fund), it's work perfectly but in some time the app crash without any message:/ so that's the reason to use this trick(slice array)

Comment: we get the same sh*t, you should get log on crash with firebase or with adb (connecting the phone with cable )

Comment: maybe you can use "tab" , each one for a categorie and with one flatlist , i use this

Comment: Yes, this in my mind I will use Sentry or firebase, "tab"? I don't get it if you can provide a screenshot!

Comment: I got this error message when app crash `Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate 77556192-byte allocation 25165824 free bytes ......` have you faced this issue before?

Comment: Replace flatflist with recyclelistview. Not so long to make it

Comment: I'm trying yesterday but i couldn't understand it  if you don't mind sharing your code snippet